# I am trying log match for last row in form submission against an index I created

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a forms responses sheet and an index sheet. The index sheet has Name, Location, Email. I am needing to get the value of the last row in form responses and find a name match in my index sheet. Then log the location and email. Right now my code finds all matches and displays them. As I stated before I only want the match for last row.

```
    function findLocation() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
  var vs1 = sh1.getRange('I3:I' + sh1.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Match');
  var vs2 = sh2.getRange('A2:C' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
  var matchRows = vs2.filter(row => row[0].length && vs1.includes(row[0]));
  matchRows.forEach(row => {
    var siteMatch = row[1];
    var emailMatch = row[2];
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(siteMatch));
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(emailMatch));
  });
}
```

Screenshot for clarification
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Description**

I made a simple test data set that I think is similar to yours.  The sample script finds the name in index sheet Match that matches the last form response row.

**Form Responses**

[image]

**Match**

[image]

**Sample script**

```
function findLocation() {
  try {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh1 = ss.getSheetByName('Form Responses');
    var vs1 = sh1.getRange(sh1.getLastRow(),1).getValue();
    var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Match');
    var vs2 = sh2.getRange('A2:C' + sh2.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var matchRow = vs2.find( row => row[0] ===  vs1 );
    Logger.log(matchRow);
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

**Execution log**

```
9:51:59 AM  Notice  Execution started
9:52:00 AM  Info    [John, A, john@somemail.com]
9:52:01 AM  Notice  Execution completed
```

**References**

- [Array.find()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)

Comment: I also need the location to display. how would I do that?

Comment: And why does it log "null"?

Comment: As shown in my Ececution log the location "A" is included with the name and email.  What do you mean by "display"? If a sheet then something like `sheet.getRange(row,col,1,matchrow.length).setValues([matchRow]);`.  And `null` means `Array.find()` didn't find a match.

Comment: I figured out why it shows null for me. The name I need to match on Form responses isn't in column A it is in column I